# Web scraper only works for a few minutes after I've opened the web page I want to scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the bit of relevant code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

item = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(item)
res = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
buyorder_table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'market_commodity_orders_table'})
print(buyorder_table)
```

When I run this code normally it prints

```
None
```

But when I open the item url in my browser, then run the code it returns the table that I want (and then I have code to parse it).

I found [this seemingly helpful article](http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2015/07/09/no-soup-for-you-when-beautiful-soup-doesnt-like-your-xml/) but I tried using the built-in HTML parser and had the same issue, which I think is the suggested solution in the article.

Is there any way to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.